# I’m trying to find the name of a manga that I read as a kid

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember that there's a kingdom and a knight who is friends with a prince. At some point he leaves the palace for a few years.

While he's gone he fights a demon then returns to the palace to save the prince, who I believe is king now, but there was a coup d'état and they are forced to flee.

It ends with the knight bowing before the prince. And then there's a time skip and now the knight is older and injured and he has a son who takes up the quest to establish order with the kingdom.